# If src and dst are the same, what will happen when I call StartCopyAsync?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

We have a new requirement where all our data needs to be encrypted at rest, and in transit for azure blob storage. We just enabled transparent encryption, so new files will be encrypted,but existing files are still left un-encrypted. We need to use a tool to re-upload the existing files so they are encrypted. My question is, **If src and dst are the same, what will happen when I call StartCopyAsync?** Will the file be corrupted? Is this a safe operation?

```
private async Task CopyContainerContents(CloudBlobContainer src, CloudBlobContainer dst)
{
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    BlobResultSegment blobSegment =  await src.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(
        prefix: "",
        useFlatBlobListing: true,
        blobListingDetails: BlobListingDetails.All,
        maxResults: null,
        currentToken: new BlobContinuationToken(),
        options: new BlobRequestOptions(), 
        operationContext: new OperationContext(),
        cancellationToken:new CancellationToken()
    );

    var blobs = blobSegment.Results.OfType<CloudBlob>().ToList();
    foreach (var blob in blobs)
    {
        CloudBlob srcBlob = (CloudBlob)blob;
        // regular file
        Console.WriteLine("Copying "+srcBlob.Name);
        CloudBlob dstBlob = dst.GetBlobReference(srcBlob.Name);
        await dstBlob.StartCopyAsync(srcBlob.Uri);
    }
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("TOTAL TIME: "+sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it? Maybe you could report back what happens.

Comment: Seems to work fine, but it IS asynchronous. So it could be a fluke that it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to say, I am disappointed that the documentation doesn't say if it would or wouldn't throw an exception when `src` is equal to `this`, i.e. `dst`.  I would start with a simple test because you might get an exception and have an immediate answer.  The documentation does say,

> Initiates an asynchronous operation to start copying **another** block
>   blob

**Note:** I am referring specifically to this method signature: [`StartCopyAsync(Uri, AccessCondition, AccessCondition, BlobRequestOptions, OperationContext, CancellationToken)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblob.startcopyasync?view=azurestorage-8.1.3#Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Blob_CloudBlob_StartCopyAsync_System_Uri_Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_AccessCondition_Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_AccessCondition_Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Blob_BlobRequestOptions_Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_OperationContext_System_Threading_CancellationToken_)

At first I thought there was some (missing) code in your for loop that would encrypt the content of `srcBlob` before writing to `dstBlob`.  But now I assume it is just not showing `Blob​Request​Options.Encryption​Policy`.

Anyway, I *think* the answer depends on your encryption, and whether or not the result of encrypting `X` bytes is `X` bytes.  Since you don't perform the encryption yourself, you can't know what is being done under the covers.

I *believe* that you would be okay when input size equals output size.  If in your first read you get say 600 bytes, you will definitely write no more than 600 bytes.  Even if you only write 300 bytes and your next read is 900 bytes, you will not write the new 900 bytes until the remaining 300 bytes from the first read have been written.

However, I wouldn't bank on an answer with too much *thinking* and *believing*.  I would definitely want to **know**.

However, even if you *can* do what you want, you **should not**.  What happens if you hit a failure in the middle of all of this?

For the sake of your customers, you should be reading in one blob and writing out to another blob.  If it is absolutely not possible for you to change the current blob path, then you need to read in the blob, write it out to a temporary blob, then on success you copy the temp blob over the old blob, then on success you delete the temp blob.

A couple other nits:

- The method should be called something that ends with Async.  It's not an absolute rule, but it is a really good policy for any method with a signature that starts with `async` and returns `Task`.
- The method isn't intended to copy anything to anywhere.  It's meant to `EncryptContainerContentsAsync`.
- The `src` is intentionally also the `dst`, so you shouldn't have both parameters or else someone in the future will be looking at your code and wondering if it is safe to use when `src` is equal to `dst`.  I think you should just take a single `container` parameter.  Then either return the new blob or do the temp swap.

One final though, when you use the `Blob​Request​Options.Encryption​Policy` you need to use a different key for each customer.  You also need a method for rotating the keys on a frequent basis, like 90 - 120 days.  I say this because I am guessing you are changing this for some compliance requirement, and sooner or later they will want this level of security.  **You** will want that level of security to protect yourself from the liability of not having it.

You should end up with a key for each customer that is stored in key vault and secure with your keys, which you also rotate.  You also probably want a table that points you to the customer's blob.  This way you can change where the customer's blob is and what keys were used as much as you want.

Comment: A lot of really good feedback. Thank you for your time on this discussion. When I originally crafted the method, its purpose was to actually copy files between two blob storage accounts. Then, when I realized I could perform an in-place encryption that would only require me to re-upload the contents of the blob, I made it so I was copying src to src. The points you bring up about EncryptionPolicy are new to me, so I'll want to do some more research on those attributes. (They don't show up for me- perhaps there is a trick there)

Comment: @Pangamma I added a link to the MSDN docs for the specific `StartCopyAsync` method I was referring to.